# How to compute dummy variable seasonality in Local Level Model?

Tags: self-study, econometrics, seasonality, state-space-models

I am attempting to understand the intuition behind the local level model that incorporates a seasonal component. I am currently reading an introductory book regarding state space modelling.

For the sake of clarity, I highlighted the parts that I could not fully understand. As is easily noticed, I do not understand how the seasonal state equations are constructed and how they are computed.

For the seasonal component $\gamma_{i,t}$, the $i$ indices relates to the $i$th quarter. For this case, we consider quarterly data. While the indices $t$ relates to the *time period*. But what is meant with the time period? The number of time increments? The year?

Could somebody clarify the seasonal state equations of the local level model with seasonal component? I would appreciate it very much.

[image]
[image]

**EDIT**

If I would follow the reasoning, I would arrive to following (trivial) identity:

$\gamma_{i,t}=\gamma_{i,t+1}$

However, the following identites adressed do not hold for the example I depicted below:

$\gamma_{2,t+1}=\gamma_{1,t}$

$\gamma_{3,t+1}=\gamma_{2,t}$

For example take $t=2$:

$\gamma_{2,3} \neq \gamma_{1,2}$

$\gamma_{3,3} \neq \gamma_{2,2}$

[image]

Comment: Here $t$ seems to be indexing year given the descriptions in the text as $t = 1,...,n$ (just below figure 4.1). So you have quarter $i$ nested in year $t$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have posted an EDIT to clarify the issue with a simple example. Would you bother to take a look at it?

Comment: Yeah I am a bit confused myself to be honest. The second highlighted part states the fourth equation -$\gamma_{2, t+1} = \gamma_{1, t}$ - implies that quarter $i$ of period $t+1$ equals quarter $i+1$ of period $t$. But this would mean $\gamma_{i, t+1} = \gamma_{i+1, t}$ which would mean $\gamma_{1, t+1} = \gamma_{2, t}$. I am clearly missing something here. Do you maybe need to substitute and do some re-arranging in Eq.4.1?

Comment: That's exactly where I get stuck. I don't believe rearranging is helpful, as the identities should be taken as a 'fact of life'. Unfortunately, that 'fact of life' remains mysterious to me